basicPublish command not working via MATLAB RabbitMQ
I am trying to access the RabbitMQ Java-Client class via MATLAB. I want to publish some message to an already defined queue in the RabbitMQ server.
However when I run the following code it gives me an error:
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

factory = ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
factory.setPort(5672);
conn = factory.newConnection()

channel = conn.createChannel

tq = channel.queueDeclarePassive("task-queue")

channel.basicPublish("","tasks",[], 'Hi') % tasks is the routing key


I get the following error:
Check for incorrect argument data type or missing argument in call to function 'basicPublish'

How to solve this error? I have checked the class but I didn't find any references to the function call.
Thanks,
Dhruv
